# Borrar n filas de una tabla

Tags: sql, plsql

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo borrar de una tabla n filas si en total cumplen la condición x filas? Donde x >>>>>> n. Lo quiero usar porque voy a tener un job que se ejecute a una hora determinada y si cada vez que se ejecute va a hacer un borrado de 100000000000 filas puede ralentizarme la BD y le quiero poner un límite de borrados por iteración.

Este delete lo cumplirían millones de registros y quiero solo borrar una cantidad x. ¿Cómo lo hago?

```
DELETE trazabilidad_pedro 
WHERE cd_intercambio = rec_mon_borrado.cd_intercambio 
AND cd_estado NOT IN ('06','07','08','09','99');`
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo más parecido que puedes hacer es usar `limit`:

```
DELETE trazabilidad_pedro 
WHERE cd_intercambio = rec_mon_borrado.cd_intercambio 
AND cd_estado NOT IN ('06','07','08','09','99') LIMIT 1000
```

Esto te eliminaría los primeros 1000 registros que cumplen esa condición.

Answer (score 1):

Si se trata de Oracle, tal como has indicado con la etiqueta `plsql`, una forma de resolverlo es aprovechando el `ROWID` de la siguiente forma, por ejemplo para borrar 1000 registros:

```
DELETE FROM trazabilidad_pedro 
    WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID
                            FROM (SELECT ROWID, 
                                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ROWID) rn
                                         FROM trazabilidad_pedro 
                                  )
                            WHERE rn <= 1000 
           )
```